# Linear, Gaussian HMM with no Process Noise vs. Linear Model

Tags: regression, bayesian, linear-model, hidden-markov-model, kalman-filter

I have been asked to implement a statistical paper for work. I have no contact with the original author, and I am confused on his approach to the problem.

He models the problem as a linear, Gaussian HMM with no process noise and known initial state $x_0$ as so

$$
x_t = kx_{t-1} \\
y_t = x_t + \varepsilon_t \\
\varepsilon_{t} \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)
$$

He then proceeds to solve the problem using a Kalman filter. I can't understand why this approach would perform any better than using a linear model. Can anyone offer any insight as to why this may be the case?